# Not retrieving correct results with mysql query using parentheses

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query all valid discounts from a mysql table.

It is setup like:

```
ID    ItemID    ProviderID    ConditionID    GradeID    DiscLimit    DiscRedeemed    DiscExp

1     0         0             3              0          10           10              0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Where `DiscExp` is a datetime.

Only one of ItemID, ProviderID, ConditionID or GradeID would ever have a value other than 0 at any given time.

I am trying to query all valid discounts, where the "limit" hasn't been reached `DiscRedeemed < DiscLimit` and it hasn't expired `DiscExp < NOW()`

Here is the query:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `store_item_discounts` WHERE 
        (ItemID > 0 AND ItemID = '$item[ID]')
        OR (ProviderID > 0 AND ProviderID = '$item[Provider]')
        OR (ConditionID > 0 AND ConditionID = '$item[ItemCondition]')
        OR (GradeID > 0 AND GradeID = '$item[ItemGrade]')
        AND (DiscLimit = 0 OR DiscRedeemed < DiscLimit) 
        AND (DiscExp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR DiscExp > NOW())        
        ORDER BY DiscType ASC");
```

Of the `$item` array, all values are 0 except for `$item['ItemCondition']` which equals 3.

For some reason, this is returning the result as shown above, where the limit has been reached. Also it doesn't filter out the dates or other variables correctly.

I obviously have something wrong with my query, but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Most likely need to put another set of parenthesis encapsulating all your OR condtions.

Comment: You can not let php substitute and array value ($item[ID]) like that in a string. You will have to either concatenate the values or use mysqli parameter binding (which is preferred since it helps in preventing sql injection)

Comment: yeah why are you using the item array like that

Comment: Probably because it's allowed and perfectly valid. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing a problem with operator precedence. Since `AND` operator has higher precedence than `OR` operator, you `WHERE` clause really looks like:

```
WHERE 
    (
        (ItemID > 0 AND ItemID = '$item[ID]')
        OR (ProviderID > 0 AND ProviderID = '$item[Provider]')
        OR (ConditionID > 0 AND ConditionID = '$item[ItemCondition]')
    ) OR (
        (GradeID > 0 AND GradeID = '$item[ItemGrade]')
        AND (DiscLimit = 0 OR DiscRedeemed < DiscLimit) 
        AND (DiscExp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR DiscExp > NOW())
    )
```

So `ConditionID = 3` is a sufficient condition to return a row. As **Uueerdo** pointed out, you need to embrace all your OR conditions in another pair of parenthesis. Your query should then look like:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `store_item_discounts` WHERE 
    (
        (ItemID > 0 AND ItemID = '$item[ID]')
        OR (ProviderID > 0 AND ProviderID = '$item[Provider]')
        OR (ConditionID > 0 AND ConditionID = '$item[ItemCondition]')
        OR (GradeID > 0 AND GradeID = '$item[ItemGrade]')
    ) AND (DiscLimit = 0 OR DiscRedeemed < DiscLimit) 
    AND (DiscExp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR DiscExp > NOW())        
    ORDER BY DiscType ASC");
```

See [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) to learn more about operator precedence.